# Is there a #line (from C) in eclipse / Aandroid land

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there an Android (compiled in Eclipse) equivalent to the **#line** directive in '**c**', and if so, how dose it work?

Comment: Java has no CPP (C Preprocessor, which provides `#xyz`) support standard. One could always run such a tool, but - not standard. There really shouldn't need to be a reason to use a `#line`-equivalent in Java though (`__LINE__/__FILE__` are different) ..

Comment: Why do you want it? For logging?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes for debugging it's nice to leave breadcrumbs (at least during early development) in the logcat messages. I know I can always leave other strings to see where I've been, but a #line directive (that doesn't need tweaking when I add/subtract lines would be something on my wish list (along with #ifdef, so I could have some code in the development/QA version, but not in production code).
-
I've seen stuff like your "__LINE__/__FILE__" comment before. could I get a bit better explanation. I'm guessing I could use that instead? - Thanks for any info - Joe

Comment: `#line` is for returning something different-than-what-is (perhaps to correct/account for a macro or whatnot). But in Java .. no need, as the other constructs don't apply. Stack traces will (usually) contain location information. Unit tests and debuggers are useful tools for debug-test-development work.

Comment: I use them all (messages to logcat, stack traces, unit tests, debuggers...) just always looking for just one more tool (and one more tool, and one more tool...) to help check the code.  Why don't you modify your comments into an answer, so I can mark it as - Accepted As An Answer - for you. Thanks for your help - Joe

Answer (score 0):

For logging, take a look at Jake Wharton's *hugo* library.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo

It does what you're trying to do with CPP.

If you annotate a method, you'll get some good logcat info.

```
@DebugLog
public ... getName(String first, String last) {}

V/Example: ⇢ getName(first="Jake", last="Wharton")
V/Example: ⇠ getName [16ms] = "Jake Wharton"
```